# Check type of object in generic function android java

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a function in my android application:

```
public static <T> void saveLocalData(Context context, String key, Class<T> value) {
    // Check type of value here
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if(value.isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
        //Put value here
    }
    else if(value.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)){
        //Put value here            
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

I want to check type of value in this function (I want to check two type `Boolean` and `String`), but I don't know how to do it! Can anyone give any suggestion? Thanks!

**Edited:** Thanks every for help! I have one more problem that is how to save it value to `Preferences`?

Comment: Could you elaborate wgat you mean by 'check type of value'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter

---

**UPDATE**: By the edit in the question, and in order to set the key/value in a [`SharedPreferences.Editor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html), use `putString()` and `putBoolean()`.

Take into account you'll need to receive the value as an argument. Notice that if you receive the value, you can already access its class (so you don't need `Class<T>` as an argument nor `isAssignableFrom()`), and check it by means of the [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator:

```
public static <T> void saveLocalData(Context context, String key, T value) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
        Constants.PREFERENCES_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if (value instanceof String) { 
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Boolean){
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Can you help me one more problem? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer. Notice that you don't need to pass the `Class` of the value if you've already got the value (which you'll anyway need to receive in the function to set the preference)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it on Android, but since it's syntax is usually equivalent to Java, here's two ways to do it in Java:

```
if (Boolean.class.equals(value) || String.class.equals(value)) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

This works because `Boolean` and `String` are both final and you don't have to worry about extended classes. I think you could even use `==` in this case (assuming a normal `ClassLoader`) as typically there's only one instance of `Class` per `Class` on the classpath. If you need to worry about extending classes, use:

```
if (Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(value) || String.class.isAssignableFrom(value)) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```